# Sudden failure with getInputStream() on JDK1.7.0_25

Tags: java, http, inputstream

I have been running a application at my work for 3years time, but all of a sudden it has decided to fail. I cannot figure out if there is an network issue involved or something entirely different.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.NegotiateAuthentication.isSupported(NegotiateAuthentication.java:99)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthenticationHeader.parse(AuthenticationHeader.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthenticationHeader.<init>(AuthenticationHeader.java:126)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1374)
    at domain.ActivationSMSReceiverMain.processLogFromUrl(SMSSys.java:327)
    at domain.ActivationSMSReceiverMain.<init>(SMSSys.java:45)
    at domain.ActivationSMSReceiverMain.main(SMSSys.java:477)
```

Code sample:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
```

I have ensured that the `uri` is well-formed (http://www.blah/?something).

Response header:

```
HTTP 200 No Error

Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 127364
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 10:31:25 GMT
```

Comment: Looks like something has changed. There are basically 3 things that could have changed: 1. The code where the exception is thrown. 2. The code that is calling the code where the exception is thrown. 3. Or some circumstances that leads to different data which leads to the exception. Case 3 would be a bug that was undiscovered until now. Which code in the stack trace was written by you or your org.? Did it change recently? Can you debug it and inspect and analyse the situation in detail (especially the parameters passed to the HTTP API)?

Comment: Do you call code in the package "sun.net.*" directly from your code?

Comment: Well. 6months ago the JDK was updated to the latest, but from that period there was no problem until now. I have contacted the 2nd party which we are getting these resources from and they have not changed anything or even made an update on their server, out of 1000 customers we are the only one which has contacted them about issues, so i assume they are telling the truth. The three last lines are written by me. I can browse through the data from any browser from the same server without any issues.

Comment: Not at all i have: `import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;`

Comment: I tried to isolate the problem in a new application and i get the error `Unknown Source`

Comment: If you don't have any other suspect, I would really try to debug it. Lets assume, that the `java.net` and `sun.net` code is free of bugs. If that is true and the server you are contacting is also working properly, than the call to the `java.net` code must be wrong in some way. A `NullPointerException` to me looks like something is wrong with the data / parameters passed to that API. I would look at that in detail by using a debugger or log output. Even if the source of the problem is somewhere else, this might get you on its track.

Comment: I vote for a Java bug: it looks like the NPE happens in the middle of a routine which checks whether SPNEGO is supported.

Comment: The remote end may be non-compliant so this could be a robustness issue with the JDK code.

Comment: You could try to use the older JRE version again and see if the NPE still occurs. If you can run the programm on your local machine, that should be easy. But it is perfectly possible, that a wrong input results in occurence of failure at a completely different place.

Comment: The Update 25 brought in major security improvements, so it is highly likely that this code is new.

Comment: Marko, without a doubt worth a try that i bounce back some versions. Which JDK would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend the one that you used before, at first try. ;)

Comment: @user573215, i dont remember the exact version, but it was 6.

Comment: Then you could try one of them. Note: I looked where exactly the NPE occurs. It happens when the HTTP library tries to access the hostname! I don't have detailed knowledge about the HTTP library's implementation, but you should definitely make sure, that the hostname your are using and passing over to the API is correct and never `null` or something like that.

Comment: Interesting. I just fell back to 1.6_45, now i receive `407`: `HTTP Error 407 Proxy authentication required`

Comment: Yes, that's consistent with my hypothesis: the proxy returns an SPNEGO handshake request, but something in the new code fails with this scenario. Try it on a Java 7, just an earlier version, before Update 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a faulty proxy server, so the problem solved itself.